# how to find the device type whether is it a computer or mobile or router etc.,

Tags: java

i have under gone a project in that i have to  know the device which use my lan ,this can have better use of my project ,instead my project is fully based on java code can any one help to find the device type in java code. i have ip address of all the system connected in my LAN with their mac address.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a very easy and straight forward issues you are having. You'll have to come up with some basic idea based on the resources you have and the platform you wish to use, and then build around that idea. You can go through the links below. Basically, the links will take you to a "How to detect mobile devices" page and this can get you some basic idea about the method and procedures you'll have to take.

These links may help:
[Detecting mobile devices in a network](http://www.hand-interactive.com/resources/detect-mobile-java.htm)

[Detecting mobile devices in a network](http://www.wirelessdevnet.com/channels/java/features/j2me_http.phtml)

Comment: sorry , i have to find the wired connected systems. event though it is not establish any network

Comment: Then it is next to impossible to know the status of a device if is not connected or rather, associated with a network that you are able to monitor or a network which you are a part of.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You can do it in client side from userAgent String.

```
String userAgent=request.getHeader(“User-Agent”);
//Check it matches to respective user agents or not.
```

Like:

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 // some code..
}
```

See this : [What is the best way to detect a mobile device in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-handheld-device-in-jquery)

**2.** Free API are available here : http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

**3.** Here you can find different ways of doing it:

http://lotusmediacentre.com/find-http-request-source-computer-mobile-phones-or-tablets/

Comment: sorry , i have to find the wired connected systems. event though it is not establish any network